# multi-to-multi indexing issue, mysql

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

i have a multi-to-multi table, this is going to have millions of rows. Let me describe my confusion with an example.

example:

table: car_dealer_rel

*opt:1*

> ```
> columns: car_id: int unsigned, dealer_id: int unsigned
> index on: car_id, dealer_id
> ```

```
car_id|dealer_id
-------|---------
1      | 1
1      | 2
....
```

- sub-opt:1: Here I can have one index on both columns.
- sub-opt:2: One combined index on 2 columns.

---

opt-2:

one column table

> ```
> col: car_id_dealer_id: varchar:21
> index on: PKI on this single column.
> ```

Here idea is to put values as: `car_id.dealer_id` and do searches as `%.xxx and or xxx.%`

```
car_id_dealer_id
----------------
1.1
1.2
1.15
2.10
...
...
```

after millions of records which will be faster for:

1. read from
2. add/update/delete.

I am novice on MySQL, all help is appreciated.

Comment: the firts one is the correct one  ..never use combined  values .. as in second sample  .. use ever separated column for separated  values  .. you can easily add composite index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with first one

```
car_id|dealer_id
-------|---------
1      | 1
1      | 2
```

you  can easlily create composite index fo both sides

```
create index  ind1 on  car_dealer_rel (car_id,dealer_id ); 

create index  ind2 on  car_dealer_rel (dealer_id, car_id );
```

that work very fast

and you can easily filter in both the sense

```
 where car_id =  your_value
```

or

```
where dealer_id = another_value
```

or using both

with the second one you can't do this easily( you need  frequently string manipulation  and this  don't let you use the index)   and in some condition you can't do using sql

and for update, insert and delete the performance remain pratically the same

Comment: Index `ind2` does not need to be composite index to save space because even without `car_id` column included, both index `ind1` and `ind2` can satisfy filtering by `car_id` and `dealer_id`, `car_id` alone or `dealer_id` alone.

Comment: not really  because the firts column could be used  in where and the second as infor for select  .. avoiding so the access to the full table  ..

Comment: I would need to use both columns for search. This is multi to multi, so rows are unique(car_id+dealer_id) but values repeat for a given column.

Comment: then you can solve all with the index  and reduce the access  to the table  this is much faster that an index  + table access ..  this is another good reason for composite index both side  (eventually you can force the use of one index  instead  of the other)  ..

Comment: [_More tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on many-to-many mapping tables.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the actual query that you use and I suggest run `EXPLAIN` first, with quite many dummy data, to understand how MySQL is going to execute your query.

But if you are going to find records by column `car_id` alone or `car_id` **and** `dealer_id`, you can use composite index (`car_id`, `dealer_id`).

If you also want to find by `dealer_id` alone, you can add additional index on `dealer_id` column.

Your one column table option is not very good because

- You cannot find rows by `dealer_id` fast.
- Table schema is not normalized.